# Using Guava's Optional with @XmlAttribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, guava

I would like to setup a JAXB-annotated Java class to generate some XML in the following format:

```
<page refId="0001">
    <title>The title of my page</title>
</page>
```

The "refId" field is optional, so I'd like to use Guava's Optional construct to reference the string in memory.  I see [Using generic @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to unmarshal wrapped in Guava's Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360139), which gives a thorough example if you're using an element (even if that wasn't the original question), but how would you set up the annotations for an XML attribute?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="page")
public final class Page {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionalAdapter.class)
    private Optional<String> refId;

    @XmlElement
    private String title;

    ... getters/setters, default constructor, etc.
}
```

And OptionalAdapter is a simple XmlAdapter:

```
public class OptionalAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<T, Optional<T>> {

    @Override
    public Optional<T> unmarshal(T v) throws Exception {
        return Optional.fromNullable(v);
    }

    @Override
    public T marshal(Optional<T> v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null || !v.isPresent()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return v.get();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to load up a unit test against the above code, it fails instantly during initialization, but if I change the annotation to @XmlElement, the test will run and pass, but obviously sets the refId as a child element instead of an attribute.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xml-attribute can have only simple type (like `String`, `Integer` etc.), so you cann't use `OptionalAdapter<T>`.
If your field has type `String` then adapter should have type `OptionalAdapter<String>`.
You  can do in next way:
  - create additional class, and use is as `XmlAdapter`

```
   public final class StringOptionalAdapter extends OptionalAdapter<String>
   {
   }
```

**Page.java**

```
   @XmlAttribute
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringOptionalAdapter.class)
   private Optional<String> refId;
```