# How to generate JaxB-Classes with java.util.Optional?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I use the jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate JaxB-Classes from a given XSD.
It works fine. 
But now I want to use java.util.Optional in the generated Classes. But JaxB generated the Classes without the Optionals. So I'm forced to make a Null-Check of every Variable.

Did anybody know how the jaxb2-maven-plugin has to be configured to use the java.util.Optional?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Working on generated classes is not good choice. Why don't enrich the xsd with  nillable="true" fields.

Comment: I agree with @Mark you should avoid to modify any generated class.
I found a similar question and It seems feasable using custom Adapter without modifying generated classes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071450/using-guavas-optional-with-xmlattribute

Comment: @Mueller , is it possible to generate variable of the class with java.util.Optional using jaxb ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find something more generic but i'm not sure if this is possible.
Anyway you can still define **custom** Adapter for types you want to be optional.

Here is an example of Integer

First, create an Adapter

```
public final class IntegerOptionalAdapter extends OptionalAdapter<Integer>
{
}
```

Then use this adapter in your binding

```
@XmlAttribute
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerOptionalAdapter.class)
private Optional<Integer> someInteger;
```

Comment: It's actually not a good idea to store optionals in fields. Better to create them in getters.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov depending, it could actually be a good idea. Opinions tend to be divided on this, and I can definitely see pro's and con's for both choices.